# Connecting adjectives in a sentence

Tags: grammar, usage, adjectives, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

If I were to say "Mr. Li is cheerful, healthy, and interesting." It would be リさんはあかるくて、げんきで、おもしろいです。

What I don't understand is how to connect negative adjectives, like if I want to say "Mr. Li is cheerful, not healthy, and not interesting."

I also don't understand how to connect past tense adjectives and negative past tense adjectives.

Like how would I say "Mr.Li was fat, wasn't healthy, and wasn't cheerful."
Or "Mr. Li wasn't fat, was healthy, and was cheerful."

Answer (score 4):

> Mr. Li is cheerful, healthy, and interesting." It would be リさんはあかるくて、げんきで、おもしろいです。

Yes, you're right.

> What I don't understand is how to connect negative adjective sentences, like if I wanna say "Mr. Li is cheerful, not healthy, and not interesting."

It would be リさんはあかるくて、げんきではなくて、おもしろくありません, word for word, but it would be more natural to say リさんはあかるいけど、げんきではなくて、おもしろくありません, connecting あかるい and the other two adjectives with a contradictory particle けど.

> I also don't understand how to connect past tense adjective sentences and negative past tense adjective sentences.

For [positive+positive+negative]:
(na-adj.)で、(na-adj.)で、(na-adj.)ではありませんでした。
(i-adj.)くて、(i-adj.)くて、(i-adj.)くありませんでした。
and [negative+negative+positive/negative]:
(na-adj.)ではなくて、(na-adj.)ではなくて、(na-adj.)でした・ではありませんでした。
(i-adj.)くなくて、(i-adj.)くなくて、(i-adj.)かったです・くありませんでした。

> Like how would I say "Mr.Li was fat, wasn't healthy, and wasn't cheerful."

リさんはふとっていて、げんきではなくて、あかるくありませんでした。
(Compare with the present tense:
リさんはふとっていて、げんきではなくて、あかるくありません。
= Mr.Li is fat, isn't healthy, and isn't cheerful.
You should just change the tense at the end of the sentence.)

> Or "Mr. Li wasn't fat, was healthy, and was cheerful."

リさんはふとっていなくて、げんきで、あかるかったです。
(Compare: リさんはふとっていなくて、げんきで、あかるいです。
= Mr. Li isn't fat, is healthy, and is cheerful.)